# Retrieve a specific DB project and its tables from SQL Server in R

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

I am new to using SQL Server from RStudio. I am connected to SQL Server from RStudio and the server has several different projects listed in the below image. For this work I am using `odbc` library. I am trying to retrieve the tables of a specific project(*Project_3960*).  I have tried `dbListTables(conn,"Project_3960")` but this command retrieve the tables from all the projects listed in the below Picture. I just want to retrieve the table which are listed in `dbo` in `Project_3690`.

The first picture is from RStudio and the second picture is from SQL Management Studio to show the structure of the folders, in case for executing SQL Query.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: `dbListTables`, by definition and intent, returns all table names found on the server within the (only!) connected database; it needs really only one argument, the connection object (your `conn`). If you need to connect to a different database, that should be addressed when you define `conn`, as in `dbConnect(..., database="Project_3960")` or such.

Comment: @r2evans I have added one more picture to show the folder structure in  SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not quite direct to retrieve the data from SQL server using *RStudio* when you have different schemas and all are connected to the server. It is easy to view the connected Databases with schema in SQL Server Management Studio but not in ***RStudio***. The easiest way while using Rodbc is to use **dot(.)** operator and its easy to retrieve the tables of a specific data base is by using **"."** with **dbGetQuery** function. I tried `dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from project_3690.dbo.AE_ISD ")` and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the arrow to the left of the `dbo` object under `Project_3690`, and it should show you the tables you have access to. If it does not, then you have a permissions problem and will need to talk with the DBA. That allows you to see them via the GUI. In fact, if you don't already know the names of the tables you should be accessing (such as to follow my code below), then this is the easiest, as they are already filtering out the system and other tables that obscure what you need.

To see them in R code, then `dbListTables(conn)` will show you all tables, including the ones in the Connections pane I just described but also a *lot* of system and otherwise-internal tables that you don't need. On my SQL Server instance, it returns over 600 tables, so ... you may not want to do just that, but you can look for specific tables.

For example, if you know you should have tables `Table_A` and `Table_B`, then you could do

```r
alltables <- dbListTables(conn)
grep("table_", alltables, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

to see all of the table names with that string in its name.

If you do not see tables that you know you need to access, then it is likely that your connection code did not include the specific database, in which case you need something like:

```r
conn <- dbConnect(odbc(), database="Project_3690", uid="...", pwd="...",
                  server="...", driver = "...")
```

(Most fields should already be in your connection code, don't use literal `...` for your strings.)

One can use a system table to find the other tables:

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_schema = 'dbo'")
#   TABLE_CATALOG TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_NAME TABLE_TYPE
# 1  Project_3690          dbo    Table_A BASE TABLE
# 2  Project_3690          dbo    Table_B BASE TABLE
# 3  Project_3690          dbo    Table_C BASE TABLE
```

(Notional output but representative of what it should look like.)

Comment: Thanks for the details. Yes I can see the table in GUI when I click on the drop down of dbo. My idea was to retrieve the table by a command that are existing in dbo. The command I executed before returns me more than 500 tables which have other tables from other projects. I just want the tables from the project_3690, which are in dbo folder.

Comment: Furthermore, Do you think another way is to connect to the specified project while connecting from Rstudio ? In that case I will only have Project_3690 but again I will need the tables from dbo and not other folders.

Comment: If you connect to `database="Project_3690"`, then `dbo` refers to tables visible to everybody in that database, `db_owner` refers to tables in that database visible only to you (give or take, a little hand-waving there). They are otherwise the same database. So you mentioning "connect to the project" is already done if you connect to `database="Project_3690"`. You want a list of tables, that is done visually (in the gui) or programmatically (with `dbListTables(conn)`).

Comment: But is there any command that can filter all the tables directly from dbo  ?

Comment: Try a query: `DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_schema = 'dbo'")`

Comment: I tried the above query and it says `Invalid Object name information_schemea.tables`

Comment: Typo, your `information_schemea` should be `information_schema`

Comment: This says, statements could not be prepared but I can retrieve one table by using `dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from project_3690.dbo.AE_ISD ")`

Comment: "Statements could not be prepared" sounds like it is in a different schema. You may be able to try `"select * from sys.tables"` instead, though I'm not familiar enough with that to know if there are known "differences" between the two. (It should still list something, however.) Regardless, it sounds like you're working with your `project_3690.dbo.AE_ISD` query, good luck!